# How to put a breakpoint on django-rest-framework package in vscode to debug?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to put a breakpoint on Create method of serializer.py located in Django-Rest-Framework in visual studio code but i am shown unverified breakpoint.

Is there a way to go deep into extrnal libraries in vscode ?

My breakpoint changes to a gray breakpoint when i want to debug extrnal libraries like below.

[image]

Comment: Tried pdb? ipdb? pudb? Or are you looking a solution specific to VSCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know something specific to VSCode but you can use Pudb to step into an external library like below:

1: Install Pudb by command below:

```
pip install pudb
```

2: Import set_trace function from Pudb module into the view.py or anywhere you want to debug like this:

```
from pudb import set_trace
```

3: Call set_trace() function anywhere of your code

4: Run python manage.py runserver by Pudb module like:

```
python -m pudb manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest **VSCode** and [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), open `launch.json` and add new configuration with parameter **"django": true**, as in example:

```
    {
      "name": "Python: Django",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/manage.py",
      "args": [
        "runserver",
        "0:8000"
      ],
      "django": true
    },
```

Comment: In 2023 you should add "justMyCode": false after "django": true